# Why is my position reference for a sheet not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to move worksheets into a new workbook. In the code I need to reference one of the sheets that has been copied, but the sheet names and code names are unpredictable so I'm trying to use a location reference. For some reason, even though everything is working perfectly, vba isn't acting on any command I give it that is using a location reference for the new workbook. No error, it just ignores it. Here are the relevant lines of code.

```
Dim SheetsToBeSaved As ArrayList
Set SheetsToBeSaved = New ArrayList
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Dim PrevMonth As String
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Sheets(i) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo SheetDoesNotExist
    End If
    If IsDate(Sheets(i).Range("B2")) Then
        If Month(Sheets(i).Range("B2")) < Month(ActiveSheet.Range("B2")) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            SheetsToBeSaved.Add i
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
SheetDoesNotExist:
Next i
For j = SheetsToBeSaved.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsToBeSaved(j)).Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsToBeSaved(j)).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next j
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
PrevMonth = MonthName(Month(wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2")))
wb.SaveAs "L:\filesrvr\Dominique\Time Reporting\Daily Timesheets\" & PrevMonth, FileFormat:=52
SheetsToBeSaved.Clear
```

Through troubleshooting, I've determined that location referencing works all the way up until I've copied the second sheet into the new workbook. If I copy ONE sheet into the new workbook, then location referencing works. The moment the second sheet is copied over, VBA will ignore any code that uses location referencing. To test I inserted the code "wb.Sheets(2).Activate" into various places and tested.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` suppresses errors, remove it and try runnign again.

Comment: What is the name of `ActiveSheet`, the worksheet with the date that you are comparing? Don't you want to exclude this worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem, I had to compile and clear errors in the code of the sheets that were being copied over. I have no idea why this was causing sheet referencing issues, but it worked.